# Why pagecontext in customtag cause Null Exception

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, custom-tags

I try to code demo about custom tag , but this problem .. I hate it, I can  solve it by my self.

here is my .TLD file:

```
<tag>
    <name>custom</name>
    <tagclass>MyTag.CustomerTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
</tag>
```

And here is my class CustomerTag:

```
public class CustomerTag extends TagSupport {

    private PageContext _pageContext;

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            _pageContext.getOut().println("kakaka"); <-- **here cause exception**
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        return SKIP_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Here is my JSP file:

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/Marko.tld"  prefix="myTag" %>
<myTag:custom />
```

Please help me, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are defining a separate `_pageContext` field that you never initialize; however, by extending `TagSupport` you should have access to a field `pageContext` that JSP initializes for you automatically.

Try removing the variable declaration and calling `pageContext.getOut().println("kakaka");` instead.